# Apache Zeppelin 0.9.0 - Helium component list is empty

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I've been using the zeppelin docker image 0.8.2 and after bringing up a container I was able to see list of helium components (from the helium menu) and enable them the enable button.
I tried to use 0.9.0 but found an empty list. What is the way to see the list again, or add components?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably in zeppelin-site.xml is missing the value zeppelin.helium.registry . Add the value in xml file and then copy in ~/zeppelin/conf directory and restart container.

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.helium.registry</name>
  <value>helium,https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json</value>
  <description>Enable helium packages</description>
</property>
```

Comment: At the time of writing https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json is returning HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden